# TypeError: function missing 1 required positional argument: 'job_id'

Tags: python, cron, task, odoo, jobs

The job_id variable is being passed through by the _process_job function which can be found in ir_cron.py file in Odoo. In my function I wish to get the currently running cron and change a custom boolean variable from True to False.

```
def log_active_running(self, job_id):
     cron = self.env['ir.cron'].browse(job_id)
            cron.write({
                'running_active': True,
            })
```

Right before I refer to the base class function _process_job I call this function which is causing the error.

```
cls.log_active_running(job['id'])
```

Once I call this function I get the error:

***TypeError: log_active_running() missing 1 required positional argument: 'job_id'***

I'm not sure what's wrong my goal is to change a variable in a currently running cron and it's giving me this error for some reason. idk what to do.

Comment: Are you calling that from an instantiation of your class, or did you literally call your class `cls`?

Comment: Right now when you call this function it thinks the first parameter is self. Could you show a basic structure of your code?

Comment: Hey, at @Reti43 yes I am.

Comment: @BuddyBobIII sure.  `@classmethod
    def _process_job(cls, job_cr, job, cron_cr):


        start_time = datetime.now()
        cls.log_active_running(job['id'])
        super(IrCron, cls)._process_job(job_cr, job, cron_cr)
        end_time = datetime.now()
        cls.log_active_running_false(job['id'])`